# Why are PIE oi changes to ī in Latin and Proto-Slavic?

Tags: latin, slavic-languages

Why are PIE oe changes to ī in Latin and Old Slavic?

English PIE Latin Old Slavic
wolves *wĺ̥kʷ**oe**s lup**i** vlĭc**i**
Is it a result of short u singular ending in place of PIE o?

English PIE Latin Old Slavic
wolf wĺ̥kʷ**o**s lup**u**s vlĭk**ŭ**

Proto-Germanic plural ending has long ō *wulf**ō**z (as I understand lengthed singular ending *wulf**a**z). If we lengthen Old Slavic short u singular ending "Ъ" we will get long ū "ЪI" and so we will have additional "I"

Comment: I'm not sure there's any answer to "why" here. It's just a thing that happened. Vowels just tend to change over time.

Comment: @Draconis I updated

Comment: Is this just two separate questions mashed into one, about Latin, and also about Slavic, or do you think there is some relationship between the two changes?

Comment: @user6726 The last paragraph is my suggestion about Slavic.

Comment: /oi/ also changed to /i/ in Greek later on, and also in Celtic. It’s not an uncommon development. The form _*wĺ̥kʷoes_ (as given by Wikipedia) is sort of archiphonemic – if it ever existed as such, it would have been in very early PIE, not relevant here: _**-o-es_ gave PIE _*-ōs_, and that’s  where the Germanic _*-ōz_ comes from, not from lengthening the singular _*-az_ (< _*-os_). The Latin, Greek and Slavic forms are all from _*u̯ĺ̥kʷoi̯_, with the pronominal plural suffix taking over from the nominal one – and with a clearer _*oi_ as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Could you give examples of "/oi/ also changed to /i/ in Greek later on"? The Slavic one has long ī on the end and that's what the question is

Comment: @fedor In Modern Greek (and ever since something like the 7th century or so, if memory serves), <οι> in Greek is pronounced /i/, so what would in Classical Greek be οἵ λύκοι /hoi lykoi/ is now /i liki/ (h has also been lost and /y/ > /i/). In all four languages mentioned, the chain of development is /oi/ > /ī/ > /i/ > /ĭ/ > /Ø/ (some of them having gone further in the chain than others).

Answer (score 5):

There's no real "why" here; vowels tend to change a lot over time, and sometimes diphthongs turn into monophthongs, or vice versa. It's just an accident of fate.

For `/oi/` in particular, `/i:/` is a pretty natural thing for it to turn into; you can think of it as the second element "taking over" the whole diphthong, or the first element assimilating completely into the second. You see this in Old Latin and in Proto-Slavic, as you mention, but there are other possibilities too: Greek turned it into `/ø(:)/` (taking the rounded-ness and mid-ness from the first element and the front-ness from the second), then `/y/` and eventually `/i/`, and post-Classical Latin turned it into `/oe/` and then to `/e:/`. Or it can just survive for a long time without changing into anything else; English has preserved `/oi/` remarkably well across time and dialects, compared to what's happened with other vowels and diphthongs.